# Dictionary Comprehension Query

Tags: python, dictionary

I wasn't able to find out how to do this elsewhere, but it is probably simple. I'm trying to capitalise the `value` associated with the dict `strings`, but am currently only able to apitalise the actual `key` itself.

```
strings = {"1234":{'a'}, "2":{'as'}, "4":{'bat'}, "5":{'car'}, "6":{'dove'}, "7":{'python'}}
```

I know this is not right:

```
d = {key:key.upper() for key in strings}
```

This resulted in an error, because I was trying to unpack too many variables:

```
d = {key:value.upper() for (key,value) in strings}
```

Comment: You need `in strings.items()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your values are sets, is that that what you wanted?

You could make them non sets and have them as strings and then use iteritems:

```
strings = {"1234":'a', "2":'as', "4":'bat', "5":'car', "6":'dove', "7":'python'}

{key: value.upper() for key, value in strings.iteritems()}
```

Alternatively if they must be sets, you need an aditional layer of iteration

```
strings = {"1234":{'a'}, "2":{'as'}, "4":{'bat'}, "5":{'car'}, "6":{'dove'}, "7":{'python'}}

{key: {val.upper() for val in value} for key, value in strings.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second attempt is on the right track, but you have two problems: to iterate over key and value simultaneously, you need the `items()` method; and you can't capitalize all the elements of a set just by calling `upper` on it. You'll need to nest a set comprehension inside the dict comprehension.

```
strings = {"1234":{'a'}, "2":{'as'}, "4":{'bat'}, "5":{'car'}, "6":{'dove'}, "7":{'python'}}

d = {key:{item.upper() for item in value} for (key,value) in strings.items()}
print d
```

Result:

```
{'1234': set(['A']), '2': set(['AS']), '5': set(['CAR']), '4': set(['BAT']), '7': set(['PYTHON']), '6': set(['DOVE'])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your value are `set` object use `str` to convert them to string then you can use `upper` method for that :

```
>>> {key: str(value).upper() for key, value in strings.items()}
{'1234': "SET(['A'])", '2': "SET(['AS'])", '5': "SET(['CAR'])", '4': "SET(['BAT'])", '7': "SET(['PYTHON'])", '6': "SET(['DOVE'])"}
```